# Rails looking for template for JSON requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my `routes.rb` I have:

```
resources :workouts
```

In my workouts controller I have:

```
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render :json => "Success" }
  end
end
```

But when I go to /workouts/1.json, I receive the following:

> ### Template is missing
>
> Missing template workouts/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/home/rails/app/views"

Which appears to show that the format is what it should be but it's still searching for a view. This same code functions in other controllers with identical setups just fine. Also, going to /workouts/1 for the html view seems to work just fine, though it also renders the html view properly when the `format.html` is removed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Looks at the source code of `render`

```
      elsif options.include?(:json)
        json = options[:json]
        json = ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(json) unless json.is_a?(String)
        json = "#{options[:callback]}(#{json})" unless options[:callback].blank?
        response.content_type ||= Mime::JSON
        render_for_text(json, options[:status])
```

Pay attention to the third line. If the value of `:json` is a string, `render` won't call `to_json` automatically for this value.

So the value remains as string and `render` will go on to search template.

To fix, supply a valid hash even for trying purpose.

```
format.json { render :json => {:message => "Success"} }
```

Comment: The original code was to render a `@workouts` object which still tried to render a view. Similarly, `format.json { render :json => {:message => "Success"} }` produces the same missing template error.

Comment: Better to paste backtrace and log if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reality check, Billy. I ended up throwing a `binding.pry` call into the show action which never fired and on further inspection I realized that there was a duplicate empty show action which is what was being called and messing everything up. My apologies to all for the nonsense, but thank you for the help.

Answer (score -1):

You would try with /workouts.json